# R Markdown Knitted PDF doc keeps showing messages even when {r, message=FALSE}

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-science

I silenced messages and it still shows the ## Setting default kernel parameters message from the ksvm function.

Keep in mind that in the original code there are 9 ksvm functions going on. I omitted most of them because stackoverflow wouldn't let me post a bunch of code with little text.

```
{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, error=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
#1
model1.ksvm <- ksvm(as.matrix(training[,1:10]),as.factor(training[,11]),
                   type='C-svc',kernel='vanilladot',C=3,scaled=TRUE)
pred <- predict(model1.ksvm,validation[,1:10])
vanilla3 <- sum(pred == validation[,11]) / nrow(validation)

#8
model1.ksvm <- ksvm(as.matrix(training[,1:10]),as.factor(training[,11]),
                   type='C-svc',kernel='laplacedot',C=6,scaled=TRUE)
pred <- predict(model1.ksvm,validation[,1:10])
lp6 <- sum(pred == validation[,11]) / nrow(validation)

#9
model1.ksvm <- ksvm(as.matrix(training[,1:10]),as.factor(training[,11]),
                   type='C-svc',kernel='laplacedot',C=10,scaled=TRUE)
pred <- predict(model1.ksvm,validation[,1:10])
lp10 <- sum(pred == validation[,11]) / nrow(validation)

tab.ksvm <- as.table(rbind(c(vanilla3, vanilla6, vanilla10), c(rbf3, rbf6, rbf10), c(lp3,lp6,lp10)))
dimnames(tab.ksvm) <- list(kernel = c("vanilladot", "rbfdot",'laplacedot'),
                      C = c("3", "6", "10"))
tab.ksvm
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/cran/kernlab/blob/master/R/ksvm.R#L88), you'll see that `ksvm` is not using `message`, it's using `cat`. That's generally bad practice (IMO, precisely for the reason you are citing), but `suppressMessages` and thus knitr's `message=FALSE` are not going to work.

You can try something like the below to capture the output from just those functions:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, error=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
#1
ign <- capture.output({
  model1.ksvm <- ksvm(as.matrix(training[,1:10]),as.factor(training[,11]),
                     type='C-svc',kernel='vanilladot',C=3,scaled=TRUE)
})
pred <- predict(model1.ksvm,validation[,1:10])
vanilla3 <- sum(pred == validation[,11]) / nrow(validation)
```
````

(Don't go too crazy with `capture.output`, though, or you'll subvert much of what `knitr` is trying to do.)

---

Proof it works (I don't have an easy `ksvm` proof handy):

````
---
title: sink check
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# test 1
  cat("hello\n")
  myvar <- 1
myvar
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
# test 2
ign <- capture.output({
  cat("hello again\n")
  myvar <- 2
})
myvar
```
````

[image: capture output test]

Comment: I was once using a java library via `rJava`, and the author thought it would be a good idea to use java's low-level print functions for a verbose running diatribe of various trace/debug statements. R doesn't intercept it as textual or console, so even this didn't work. Ugh. I wish package authors would spend another moment thinking about automated use of their code ... glad it worked!